# How to make Lightroom Tutorial at lightroom.adobe.com/learn/tutorial/

Tags: adobe-lightroom

[image]Currently, I can share my edits from adobe Lightroom, so Lightroom users can use my edit as preset or they can learn, how I edited my photos.
But I saw a 'Learn' option in Lightroom where Editors shared detailed editing tutorials.
https://lightroom.adobe.com/learn/tutorial/

My question is, Can I make similar tutorials in Lightroom? and How?

Comment: You can make videos of yourself doing edits in Lightroom but you need some type of a screen capture/recording application. Lightroom itself does not have the ability to create these videos.

Comment: No, Lightroom tutorials in 'Lightroom learn' are not videos. They are kind of edit assistants. They show popup message that tells how to edit. And with that, we can edit the same in 'light room'.

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of 'lightroom lean', check that

Comment: This is really a question for the Adobe community. Note Adobe doesn't just let *anyone* write tutorials under the umbrella of their product/company. It's very unlikely an unknown user can contribute to application-integrated content.

Comment: At the *very least* you need to actually write your own tutorials and host them somewhere and gain an audience. *Then* Adobe may consider adding you as a contributor. Adobe pulls from "known users/experts" to contribute. In other words, ya gotta kinda have some notoriety regarding the app first. -- of course.. I've never used the feature you refer to here.... so I could be off base with all of this for Lightroom. I'm just a little experienced with this regarding *other* applications.